# Order of Exception evaluations

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python exceptions, does the `TypeError` check occur before doing the `ValueError` check? For example:

```
>>> chr(123)
'{'

>>> chr('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

>>> chr(18293939)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)

>>> chr(1829393993939393)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum
```

Or what is the order in which the various errors are checked? Is there documentation on the order of operations/evaluations for the difference Exception types?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `chr` and the Python implementation. The builtin `chr` in CPython [is implemented in c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e3babbd03cd2bcb3c85deabae3bc6976aa95a3c3/Python/bltinmodule.c#L686), which calls [`PyUnicode_FromOrdinal`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6876257eaabdb30f27ebcbd7d2557278ce2e5705/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L3215).  From the looks of that, `ValueError` is indeed checked first, before passing onto `unicode_char` which has the additional checks.

Comment: Well, actually, the `TypeError` to guard against invalid type is checked first, as the actual implementation of `chr` is in [`bltinmodule.c.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b104ecbbafc14f9ca0c8371963c45dca893f6b75/Python/clinic/bltinmodule.c.h#L132) which is then passed onto `bulitin_chr_impl`, which I linked in the last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of this is documented (*i.e.*, guaranteed).  That said, it would be impossible to raise a sensible `ValueError` if there was no *value* of the correct type to compare.  The difference between `ValueError` and `OverflowError` is surely an implementation detail entirely, since anything that overflows the target type would of course be out of any restricted range for that type.